# Getting 'instance' variable from parent metaclass

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

With the following code, in what way can I access `@arr` from `Child`?

```
class Parent
    class << self
        def create_singleton_variable
            @arr = [1,2,3]
        end

        def arr
            @arr
        end
    end
end

class Child < Parent
    def get
        puts self.arr
    end
    def self.get 
        puts self.arr
    end
end


p "class method call #{Child.get}"
#=> ➜ ruby child.rb    
#=> "class method call "

c = Child.new
p "instance call #{c.get}"
#=> ➜ ruby child.rb 
#=> Traceback (most recent call last):
#=>        1: from child.rb:24:in `<main>'
#=> child.rb:15:in `get': undefined method `arr' for #<Child:0x00007fe0eb02e7d8> (NoMethodError)
```

I've tried many other ways as well, but don't feel the need to post them here.

edit to the question, since it appears I do need a bit more context:

I'm attempting to prepend a module into the `Thor` framework. I want to then access [this bit of code](https://github.com/erikhuda/thor/blob/d3762d0b89a80da488285d640b052f5276fac6bb/lib/thor.rb#L221)

```
module ThorExtensions
  module Thor
    module CompletionGeneration
      def self.prepended(base)
        base.singleton_class.prepend(ClassMethods)
      end

      module ClassMethods
        def completion
          puts "Start Completion"
          p self
          p self.superclass
          p self.class.superclass.subcommands
          puts "End Completion"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

results in

```
Start Completion
Debug
Thor
bundler: failed to load command: exe/pt (exe/pt)
NoMethodError: undefined method `subcommands' for Module:Class
  /Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/pt-cli/lib/thor_extensions/completion_generation.rb:13:in `completion'
  /Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/pt-cli/lib/debug/debug.rb:24:in `<class:Debug>'
  /Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/pt-cli/lib/debug/debug.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/pt-cli/lib/pt.rb:5:in `require'
  /Users/tyler.thrailkill/Documents/code/backend/pt-cli/lib/pt.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  exe/pt:13:in `require'
  exe/pt:13:in `<top (required)>'
```

which of course is not what I want. It appears that maybe my issue is with prepending?

#### Edit 2

I seem to have done a terrible job of explaining my issue with prepending. Here is a fully working example showing my issue. I believe this is due to how prepending something to a class essentially creates another Class in the call stack that is called first. My hope is that I'm actually still able to access this method somehow.

```
class Parent
  class << self
    def create_singleton_variable
      @arr = [1,2,3]
      puts "arr is initialized #{@arr}"
    end
    # ... lots of code here. 
    def arr
      puts "arr is #{@arr.inspect}"
      @arr
    end
  end
end

module CompletionGeneration
  def self.prepended(base)
    base.singleton_class.prepend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def completion 
      puts "self.superclass.arr == #{self.superclass.arr.inspect}" # unable to access superclass arr
      puts "self.class.superclass.arr == #{self.class.superclass.arr}" # likewise, unable to access Child's metaclass superclass 
    rescue Exception => e
      # do nothing, this is just so you can see arr is actually initialized in the context of the Child
      p e
    end
  end
end

Parent.prepend CompletionGeneration

class Child < Parent
  create_singleton_variable
  completion
  arr
end

Child.new
```

results in the output

```
➜ ruby child.rb
arr is initialized [1, 2, 3]
arr is nil
self.superclass.arr == nil
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `arr' for Module:Class>
arr is [1, 2, 3]
```

This code should be simply copy and pastable as is.

Comment: In light of your edit I deleted my answer for now, but will  revisit the question after I return from an outing with Saffi, my faithful canine companion.

Comment: I've found this, which is tantalizingly close to what I want. http://wiseheartdesign.com/articles/2006/09/22/class-level-instance-variables/, but it uses includes, rather than prepends. I need to prepend (well maybe not _need_, but I'd like to) into Thor. I also can't access `subcommands` or the like until after they've been initialized by other class level methods.

Comment: Theoretically I thought I should be able to access any methods in `Thor`, but for some reason they don't seem to be the same 'context' as the regular thor calls, resulting in empty arrays or hashes being returned. I did forget to mention that I don't really have trouble calling the methods on the object, but they're never populated, I'm guessing due to that.

Comment: With more research, I'm actually able to access `Thor::Base` methods for some reason, but still not `Thor` class methods themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code, slightly modified.

```
class Parent
  def self.create_singleton_variable
    @arr = [1,2,3]
  end 
  def self.arr
    puts "self = #{self} in the getter for @arr"
    @arr
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def get
    puts self.arr
  end
  def self.get 
    puts self.arr
  end
end
```

I have written `Parent` in the more conventional way. Except for the addition of the `puts` statement, it is equivalent to that contained in the question.

First, a head-slapper: [Kernel#puts](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-puts)-anything returns `nil`. You need to remove `puts` from both methods:

```
class Child < Parent
  def get
    self.arr
  end
  def self.get 
    self.arr
  end
end

Parent.create_singleton_variable
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 
Child.get.nil?
self = Child in the getter for @arr
  #=> true
```

We see that within the getter `arr`, invoked by `Child`'s class method `get`, `self` equals `Child`, so the method looks for a class instance variable `@arr` of `Child` not of `Parent`. As no such instance variable has been initialized, `nil` is returned.

You need the following.

```
class Parent
  class << self
    def create_singleton_variable
      @arr = [1,2,3]
    end
    def arr
      puts "self = #{self} in the getter for @arr"
      @arr
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def get
    self.class.superclass.arr
  end
  def self.get 
    superclass.arr
  end
end
```

The crucial difference to that given in the question is that [Class#superclass](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Class.html#method-i-superclass) changes the scope (i.e., `self`) to `Parent`.

We see the desired result is obtained.

```
Child.get
self = Parent in the getter for @arr
  #=> [1, 2, 3] 

Child.new.class.superclass.arr
self = Parent in the getter for @arr
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

A common misconception is that the `Child` class method defined `def self.get; self.arr; end` invokes the getter `Parent::arr`, and therefore returns the value of `Parent`'s instance variable `@arr`. It is `Child::arr` that is invoked, however, that method having been inherited from `Parent`, and it is `Child`'s class instance variable `@arr` that is being retrieved, a subtle, but important, distinction.

**Edit 2**

The first observation is that `Parent` can be written in the more conventional (and completely equivalent) way.

```
class Parent
  def self.create_singleton_variable
    @arr = [1,2,3]
    puts "arr is initialized #{@arr}"
  end

  def self.arr
    puts "arr is #{@arr.inspect}"
    @arr
  end
end
```

Regardless of how its written, `self` will equal `Parent` when either class method is involked on parent. The first, therefore, will create the class instance variables `@arr`.

```
Parent.methods(false)
  #=> [:create_singleton_variable, :arr] 
Parent.instance_variables
  #=> []
Parent.ancestors
  #=> [Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Now let's create a class variable for `Parent`.

```
Parent.create_singleton_variable
  # arr is initialized [1, 2, 3]
Parent.instance_variables
  #=> [:@arr]
```

Now let me change the value of `@arr`.

```
Parent.instance_variable_set(:@arr, ['dog', 'cat'])
  #=> ["dog", "cat"]
Parent.arr
  # arr is ["dog", "cat"]
  #=> ["dog", "cat"]
```

Next, create the class `Child`, but do not yet prepend the module.

```
class Child < Parent
  create_singleton_variable
  arr
end
arr is initialized [1, 2, 3]
arr is [1, 2, 3]

Child.ancestors
  #=> [Child, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
Child.instance_variables
  #=> [:@arr] 
Child.instance_variable_get(:@arr)
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

There are no surprises. Next load the module.

```
module CompletionGeneration
  def self.prepended(base)
    base.singleton_class.prepend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def completion
      puts "self=#{self}"
      puts "superclass=#{superclass}"
      puts "self.class=#{self.class}"
      puts "self.class.superclass == #{self.class.superclass}" 
      puts "superclass.arr == #{superclass.arr.inspect}"
      puts "self.class.superclass.arr == #{self.class.superclass.arr}" 
      rescue Exception => e
        # do nothing, this is just so you can see arr is actually
        # initialized in the context of the Child
        puts "Exception => e=#{e}"
    end
  end
end
```

(Note `self.` is not needed in `"superclass.arr == #{superclass.arr.inspect}"`) Now prepend this module to `Parent`.

```
Parent.prepend CompletionGeneration

Parent.ancestors
  #=> [CompletionGeneration, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
Parent.methods.include?(:completion)
  #=> true 
Child.ancestors
  #=> [Child, CompletionGeneration, Parent, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
Child.methods.include?(:completion)
  #=> true
```

The callback modules method `CompletionGeneration::prepended` is fired with `base` equal to `Parent`, causing `Parent`'s singleton class to prepend `ClassMethods`, thereby adding the class method `Parent::completion`. Since `Parent` did not previously have a method by that name using `prepend` or `include` would have the same effect. Further, instead of `Parent.singleton_class.include ClassMethods`, one could have used the `included(base)` callback instead, and executed `Parent.extend ClassMethods`. Perhaps `prepend` is being used here for a general case where `Parent` may have a class method by that name.<sup>1</sup>

Now execute the following.

```
Child.completion
self=Child
superclass=Parent
self.class=Class
self.class.superclass == Module
arr is ["dog", "cat"]
superclass.arr == ["dog", "cat"]
Exception => e=undefined method `arr' for Module:Class
```

The exception was raised when

```
puts "self.class.superclass.arr == #{self.class.superclass.arr}"
```

was being executed. As that amounts to

```
puts "self.class.superclass.arr == #{Module.arr}"
```

but of course `Module` has no module method `arr`.

<sup>1 In view of `Child.ancestors`, prepending `Parent` with the module only causes `Parent`'s children to `include` (rather than `prepend`) the module; that is, if a child already has a method `completion` before the prepending, that method will not be preempted by the the module's method by the same name.</sup>

Comment: Yes, sorry, my example was a bit _too_ simplified for my actual use case sadly. So, accessing in a static context of course works, but I'm actually trying to prepend a module into a library to then access variables in this way.

Comment: I've edited my question to be a bit more clear about what I'm actually trying to do.

Comment: I seem to have made myself come across as an idiot. I understand all that, including the common misconception you stated. I've updated my question with a fully working example showing what I believe the actual issue to be (something with prepending). Yes I did have a few typos in my first example where I was printing stuff, but it shouldn't have mattered since I was printing in both locations, it would have printed at some point. This new example fully illustrates the issue with proper output, replicating exactly the issue I'm having.

Comment: And thank you for your time helping me with this. Bit frustrating is all. I believe the issue is that prepending essentially just adds a new class with methods to the bottom of the call stack, but what I don't know is what the solution to this problem is.

Comment: any clue on what I can do? I've succeeded at getting this working with monkey patching the relevant class, but I'd rather prepend it so I can pull it out into a library

Comment: @snowe, sorry for not replying earlier. I'll have a look at this shortly.

Comment: No worries! just a small bump since I got it working with monkey patching. I'd just thought maybe you could think of a nicer solution.

Comment: @snowe, I hope this most recent edit helps, but I confess I still don't understand the crux of your question.

Comment: Ok so it looks like what I _might_ have been doing wrong (I don't have the old code to reference) was calling `superclass.arr` from within the prepended module. Instead I call just `arr` and it works! I've marked your answer as the answer so thank you for all your help!

Comment: Glad to be of help.